# How to prevent VScode from closing editor when pressing ctrl+w with no tabs open?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, ide, key-binding

According to the comment here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50671 it's possible to edit this behavior in the keybindings, but provides no instructions for how to do so.

How do I edit the VScode keybindings so that if I press CTRL+W with no open tabs, it doesn't close the editor? It's highly annoying to be trying to close a bunch of tabs and then accidentally close the entire editor.

Comment: You have verified that the shortcut is not listed within the keybindings editor?

Answer (score 26):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts (or press Ctrl+K Ctrl+S).

Find the "Close Window" setting with Ctrl+W as the Keybinding.

Right click and remove the key binding or edit it to another combination.

Comment: Works for me. TY

Comment: This is not half as good or as nuanced as using the `when` condition.

Comment: I agree regarding the nuance, but some people like working through the UI instead of editing a text file.  My answer and harrymc's together give them options based on their comfort level.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug:
[#54583 Closing last editor with Ctrl+W closes VS Code (regression)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54583),
which seems to be a reversion to a previous behavior.

The solution is found in another bug-report:
[#53730 User keybindings break if conditions on the default binding change](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53730),
which is to edit the file `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`.

Somewhere in the file you should find the following code:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+w",
  "command": "-workbench.action.closeWindow",
  "when": "!editorIsOpen"
}
```

Change the "when" condition so that this looks like:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+w",
  "command": "-workbench.action.closeWindow",
  "when": "!editorIsOpen && !multipleEditorGroups"
}
```

Note that this is marked as fixed, so the bug might be fixed in some upcoming
version of VS Code.

Comment: It workeddd!! You're the best! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, issue is still present in VS Code

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue. Adding this in keybindings.json file helps:

```
{
      "key": "cmd+w",
      "command": "-workbench.action.closeWindow",
      "when": "!editorIsOpen && !multipleEditorGroups"
}
```

This will close active editor by cmd+w . But will not close the vscode window when no editor is open.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the recent version, 1.43.1, in the `keybindings.json` user setup:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type: `view close editor` to filter the shortcuts
3. Find item *View: close editor* with the keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and right-click it.
4. Select the item *Change when expression* in the context menu
5. Type: `!editorIsOpen` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Restart VS Code